# What should I do with this error? unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

I have database with name 'Data' :

```
#removing NULL from database
data_new2 = Data.copy()
data_new2.dropna(inplace = True)
```

then I did

```
#calculating deposit
data_new2list=['DATA6030','DATA6040']
data_new2['deposit']=data_new2[data_new2list].astype(float).sum(1)

data_new3=data_new2
data_new3['WFR']= data_new3['DATA9960']/data_new3['DATA6190']
data_new3['DR']=data_new3['deposit']/data_new3['DATA6190']`
```

However, I received this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: Are you trying to divide `/` two strings?

Comment: I dont know they are string or not as I know they are numbers but because there is a big data I cannot check if there is string on it or not!

Comment: `data_new3.dtypes`.

Comment: there are some 'objects' type . how can I change the type of it?

Answer (score 1):

You are performing a division operation between two strings, convert your columns to make it work:

```py
data_new2 = Data.copy().astype(float)
```

Comment: where should I put this code?

Comment: You can convert it directly on copy: `Data.copy().astype({'DATA6030':float, 'DATA6040'float})`

Comment: Is your dataframe supposed to have only numbers?

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax  I got this error. yes numbers

Comment: So convert your entire df to floats: `data_new2 = Data.copy().astype(float)`

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that 'DATA9960' and 'DATA6190' columns contain at least one string each, and you can't divide two strings.

Assuming that those columns can contain non-numeric strings, first convert all the numeric strings to a numeric type, using [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`. The non-numeric strings will be set to NaN.

```
import pandas as pd

data_new2 = Data.copy()
data_new2.dropna(inplace=True)

data_new2list = ['DATA6030','DATA6040']
data_new2['deposit'] = data_new2[data_new2list].astype(float).sum(1)

#convert 'DATA9960', 'DATA6190' to numeric 
cols = ['DATA9960', 'DATA6190']
data_new2[cols] = data_new2[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

# drop rows with NaN values in 'DATA9960', 'DATA6190' resulting from pd.to_numeric
data_new2.dropna(subset=cols, inplace=True)

# this doesn't return a copy btw. data_new3 and data_new2 point to the same object. 
# To make a copy you need data_new3 = data_new2.copy()
data_new3 = data_new2   

data_new3['WFR'] = data_new3['DATA9960'] / data_new3['DATA6190']
data_new3['DR'] = data_new3['deposit'] / data_new3['DATA6190']`
```

Comment: it works but the problem is that in data_new3 I still have NaN value while on the above I tried to remove Null at first :    `#removing NULL from database
data_new2 = Data.copy()
data_new2.dropna(inplace = True)`

Comment: Then put the  `dropna` line only after using  `pd.to_numeric`.  Should  `data_new2`  only contain numeric values in all columns? Do you want to drop all the rows of `data_new2` that contain at least one non-numeric string?

Comment: I did not get where shall I put `dropna`. no I have columnc like country and name which are not numeric.  I want to drop all nan in all my dataframe

Comment: I've included it in my answer. Does it solve your issue?

Comment: No. it still shows the NaN! before all these codes I tried to change .n to NaN in my dataframe with this : `Data = Data.replace('.n','NaN')` is it because of that code?

Comment: Well, then provide a minimal reproducible example in your post description. I can't guess what is wrong if I can't reproduce the problem. Share a sample of `data_new2` and the corresponding output with the NaN values still showing.